# How do I make this R code to format integers with leading zero more succinct?

Tags: r, purrr

I have created a function called `interval` which takes two numbers as input between 1 and 12 and if the number is less than 10, it appends a 0 to the front. e.g. 4 becomes 04, but 11 stays 11.

```
interval <- function(month_start = 1, month_end = 12){
    month_range <- as.character(c(month_start:month_end))
    month_range_char <- month_range %>% 
      map(
        ~if(as.numeric(.x)<10){
          paste0("0",.x)
        }
        else{
          .x
        }
      )
return(month_range_char)

}
```

I feel like I have written a lot of code to do quite a simple thing. Is there an obvious way to improve this?

Comment: The `sprintf` function will do this for you: `sprintf("%02d", 4:11)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
x <- 1:12

ifelse(x < 10, paste0("0", x), x)

# and to force a character variable, per comment from @Miff
as.character(ifelse(x < 10, paste0("0", x), x))
```

Output:

```
[1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```

Since vectors all have to be the same type, they will all return characters so you dont need the switching back and forth between `as.character` and `as.numeric` as in your code.

Or if you want to wrap in a function:

```
add0 <- function(input){
  ifelse(x < 10, paste0("0", input), input)
}
```

Or perhaps the best way is as @MrFlick says in the comments (since not everyone reads them)

```
sprintf("%02d", x) #Thanks @MrFlick
```

Comment: Note that this approach has the potential bug that the type of result depends on the value of `x`. i.e. if there are no single digit numbers in `x` it will return a numeric vector, if there are single digit numbers it will return a character vector. Suggest wrapping the output in `as.character()` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
test <- as.character(c(5, 10))

library(stringr)

ifelse(str_length(test) == 1, str_pad(test, 2, pad = "0"), test)

[1] "05" "10"
```